# Order by combined joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have table "user_following"(all the subs that the users follow) with `user_id(int(10)) and follow_sub(varchar(30))`

"user_likes"(all the likes of the users) table with `user_id(varchar(15)) and post_sub(varchar(15))`

and "user_post" with `user_id(int(10)) post_txt(text) sub_id(varchar(30) parallel to follow_sub) post_unix_time(float)`

I have 2 ways to order the posts:

1) By the newest posts, of the subs, that the user follow:

```
        $result11="SELECT * FROM user_post
        INNER JOIN users_following ON user_post.sub_id=users_following.follow_sub
        WHERE  users_following.user_id='$userid' 
        ORDER BY user_post.post_id DESC";
```

2) By algorithm that count the likes of each article, BUT WITH ALL THE SUBS(even if the user doesn't follow them):

```
        $result11="SELECT user_post.*, (LOG10(ABS(COUNT(user_likes.post_id)) + 1) * SIGN(COUNT(user_likes.post_id)))/user_post.post_unix_time AS like_count
                    FROM user_post LEFT JOIN user_likes 
                    ON user_post.post_id = user_likes.post_id
                    GROUP BY user_post.post_id
                    ORDER BY like_count desc;";
```

I want to combine both of the joins- to present the posts to the user of the subs he follow, with LIKES ALGORITHM.

This is how I tried to do it, but it show me error-`mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in`:

```
            $result11="SELECT user_post.*, (LOG10(ABS(COUNT(user_likes.post_id)) + 1) * SIGN(COUNT(user_likes.post_id)))/user_post.post_unix_time AS like_count
            FROM user_post.*
            LEFT JOIN user_likes ON user_post.post_id = user_likes.post_id
            INNER JOIN users_following ON user_post.sub_id=users_following.follow_sub
            WHERE  users_following.user_id='$userid' 
            GROUP BY user_post.post_id
            ORDER BY like_count DESC";
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: surely FROM userpost.* should be FROM userpost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its giving a boolean as whatever flavour of mysql or mysqli you are using is returning false rather than a statement object as you have invalid sql

`FROM userpost.*`

should be

`FROM userpost`

Comment: hmmm wowww... I didn't expect it to be so easy to solve it. Thank you